# Ruby: LoadError Incompatible Library Version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I try to run my rails project, I receive the following LoadError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    22: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    21: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    20: from /Users/marko/WebDevSchool/hello_U_official_files/helloU/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from /Users/marko/WebDevSchool/hello_U_official_files/helloU/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    18: from /Users/marko/WebDevSchool/hello_U_official_files/helloU/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    17: from /Users/marko/WebDevSchool/hello_U_official_files/helloU/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    16: from /Users/marko/WebDevSchool/hello_U_official_files/helloU/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    15: from /Users/marko/WebDevSchool/hello_U_official_files/helloU/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    14: from /Users/marko/WebDevSchool/hello_U_official_files/helloU/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    13: from /Users/marko/WebDevSchool/hello_U_official_files/helloU/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    12: from /Users/marko/WebDevSchool/hello_U_official_files/helloU/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
    11: from /Users/marko/WebDevSchool/hello_U_official_files/helloU/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `require'
    10: from /Users/marko/WebDevSchool/hello_U_official_files/helloU/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Users/marko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
     8: from /Users/marko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
     7: from /Users/marko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
     6: from /Users/marko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
     5: from /Users/marko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
     4: from /Users/marko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
     3: from /Users/marko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
     2: from /Users/marko/WebDevSchool/hello_U_official_files/helloU/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/marko/WebDevSchool/hello_U_official_files/helloU/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
```

/Users/marko/WebDevSchool/hello_U_official_files/helloU/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/marko/WebDevSchool/hello_U_official_files/helloU/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle (LoadError)

I have tried:

1. `gem pristine --all`
2. `gem uninstall bcrypt` & `gem install bcrypt`
3. `gem uninstall railties` & `gem install railties`

Nothing has been working so far

Comment: I'm getting the same error - did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Yes but for the life of me I cannot remember the exact solution. Thinking back, it could have been a matter of switching from rvm to rbenv or vice versa.

Comment: No guarantees that above answer will work though. FYI

Comment: Thanks for responding! I actually asked a question on SO too but no one answered, and ultimately this was the solution for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56522059/11249670